# Index on each function not defined

Tags: jquery

This might be a stupid question but since I'm new in this I want to ask you if this is a right code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".note-float").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass("note-float-view");
  }, index * 500);
});
```

Since I always get an error stating `index is not defined`. What did I actually miss? The `.note-float` class is available and never being hidden.

Comment: Ah - index is only scoped to be within your function. Once you get passed that ending curly brace just before `, index * 500` its out of scope and doesn't exist any more.

Comment: The question never says what `index * 500` is supposed to do there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `index` outside of the anonymous function (callback), so it's out of scope when you come to use it.

The way you have written it, `index * 500` is being used as the second parameter to `.each` and that doesn't accept a second parameter (Not the method you are using anyway).

Edit: To add the new class to the element at a different speed (taking the `index` in to account, you can use a `settimeout`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".note-float").each(function(index) {
    // save a reference to this element so we can use it in the timeout
    var el = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function () {
      el.addClass("note-float-view")
    }, index * 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.note-float-view, .note-float {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.note-float-view {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="note-float"></div>
<div class="note-float"></div>
<div class="note-float"></div>
<div class="note-float"></div>
```

Comment: If this is the case, is there any way to make the note class shows in different speed (one by one)?

Comment: Sure, I assumed that's what you were after. I'll edit my answer